# how can we route without controller in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have to route my mvc application like , www.MySite.com/User123. Just like facebook do, http://facebook.com/UserId will describe all the user information. 
 I tried this But Its not working.

```
routes.MapRoute( _
          name:="Default", _
          url:="{id}", _
          defaults:=New With {.id = "user"} _
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to route to a specific controller and action without having them in the URL, you need to specify them as defaults. Your route for this would be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "{id}"
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Show" }
);
```

This would give you a route that would map "http://www.mysite.com/user123" to the `Show` action on the `ProfileController`, passing `user123` as the ID parameter.

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Show(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, however, since this route is very generic and would catch-all I would recommend that you add a constraint on `{id}`. Otherwise, routes that would not be userIDs would also be caught. So if the userIDs follow some kind of pattern, add a regEx constraint.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta This wouldn't catch everything; it would only catch URLs that only have a single path segment. Moreover, less general routes could quite easily be placed before this one. Though I agree that if there is a pattern that can be used to match user IDs, it can't hurt to constrain the route parameter.

Comment: I've worked on a number of projects that simply defined more specific routes before the final route - i.e., if it doesn't hit anything known, like "/help/{controller}/{action}/{id}" then it must be a user ID.

Comment: How can i distinguish between My Custom route using "HOME" Controller like, 
routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Default", _
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )

Comment: Put the `Profile` route first and URLs with multiple segments won't match. If you're using URLs with only one segment that aren't user IDs, you're out of luck - there's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: :( ... It means  example.com/home will be considered as "HOME" controller action..

Comment: Well... yeah? How do you expect the MVC routing to know that "home" is a controller but "user123" is a user ID? The only other option is to route everything through the Home controller action, check if it's a valid ID in the action and redirect to a profile if it is.

Comment: which is the **best** way to get value of id in url? like example.com/user445
 i want user445 in a variable?

Comment: Make it an action parameter like in the code in my answer.

Comment: I am using ,
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("id")
 So which is the **BEST** way?

Comment: Action parameters. That's what they're for.